# What is Follow(X) when there's a rule, A -> XBCD where First(B) and First(C) contain empty, but First(D) do not

Tags: parsers

I have a question about follow sets.

Suppose there's a rule,

> A -> XBCD
>
> B -> $\beta$ | $\epsilon$
>
> C -> $\gamma$ | $\epsilon$
>
> D -> $\delta$

What is Follow(X)?

Is it (First(B) - $\epsilon$) $\cup$  (First(C) - $\epsilon$) $\cup$ First(D) = {$\beta$ , $\gamma$, $\delta$ } ?

Comment: $FOLLOW(X)$ is the set of symbols which might immediately follow $X$ in some derivation. FWIW, It's conventional to use Greek letters for *sequences* of symbols (with $\epsilon$ representing the empty sequence); based on that understanding, I would have said that $FOLLOW(X)$ is $FIRST(\beta)\cup FIRST(\gamma) \cup FIRST(\delta)$. But perhaps you mean those Greek letters to be terminals.

Comment: I've got it! Yeah, I used Greek letters as terminals, but I now understand that this is not usual. With this in mind, I read the book again, and finally I get it! As you say, they are using Greek letters as sequences of symbols. 
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. As @rici made a comment, I misunderstood the meaning of Greek letters in the discussion of Follow sets in the book I am reading. Greek letters mean sequences of symbols.

Using the definition,

> If there is a production B-> $\alpha$ A $\gamma$, then First ($\gamma$)
>    - {$\epsilon$} is in Follow (A)

First(BCD) is in Follow(X) where

> A -> XBCD

BCD corresponds to $\gamma$ in the definition.